# how can i scroll a label field with lots of data in blackberry storm

Tags: blackberry

i have a screen that contains one label field
which contains lots of data

i have placed that label filed inside the vertical field manager but still i cannot scroll.

what could be the possible reason

i searched and tried many ways but no success.

some told me to place null fileds
or use many labels etc  but what to do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey once i faced the same problem

why don't you try using Edit field.
It will scroll automatically

use

```
String str="lots of data..............................";
EditField edit = new EditField();
edit.setText(str);
```

Make it FOCUSABLE and READONLY and add it to a VerticalFieldManager with VERTICAL_SCROLL (and potentially VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR).  TextField and its descendants can have the focus inside the field (the cursor).  That is how you let the user scroll it.

Comment: i feel u r correct but isn't there any option to go ahead with label field